# React Redux appending/removing from an array within state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I've got an array within the state object which I need to push or splice items from. How can we implement it without mutating the products array? Would something like this work?

```
const Cart = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT':
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [...state.products, action.product]
      }

    case 'REMOVE_PRODUCT':
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [
          ...state.products, ...state.products.slice(0, action.index).concat(state.products.slice(action.index + 1))
        ]
      }
  }
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I need to add/remove items from the products array within the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work, as you don't mutate your existing state & always return a new state.
Extra: make sure you also add

```
  default:
    return state
```

To prevent state loss when you throw an action that's not defined in your reducer.

Comment: Thanks for the assurance.

Answer (score 1):

You code will work, however it would be more cleaner to do it like

```
case 'REMOVE_PRODUCT':
  return {
    ...state,
    products: [
      ...state.products.slice(0, action.index),
      ...state.products.slice(action.index + 1)
    ]
  }
default: return state
```

Also as @sn_92 pointed out that you should have a default condition in case you have call an action that is not defined in the above reducer.

Comment: Thanks, if we don't include the ...state.products, would't this mutate the array?

Comment: since we are using spread operators it returns you a new array so ...state.products isn't actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the remove case in a better way like this, however there is a small change you will need to do. Instead of passing `index` in action, pass `value` to be removed (much cleaner way to do things):

```
case 'REMOVE_PRODUCT':
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.filter(item => item !== action.value)
  }
```

Let me know if this helps